# Does the countable $\sigma$-product of a separable Hilbert space have a first countable topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $\mathcal{l}^2$ be "the" separable real infinite dimensional hilbert space, e.g. the space of square-summable sequences of real numbers.

Let $\Box^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{l}^2$ be the countable product of $\mathcal{l}^2$ with itsself with the box product topological, i.e. the topology on $\Pi_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{l}^2$ induced by the sets of the shape $\Pi_{i\in\mathbb{N}}U_i$ where $U_i\subseteq\mathcal{l}^2$ is open for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

Consider the subspace $$\Sigma^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{l}^2=\{(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\Pi_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{l}^2|x_i\neq 0\text{ for only finitely many }i\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq\Box^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{l}^2$$ of all elements having only finitly many nonzero entries with the subspace topology.

Since already $\Box^{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}$ is not first countable, $\Box^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{l}^2$ will certainly not be first countable.

> Is $\Sigma^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{l}^2$ first countable?

This seems somehow plausible, because we imposed a finiteness condition on $\Sigma^{\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{l}^2$ which might lead to first-countability, but I was neither able to proof it (or find a reference) nor to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

Even $\Sigma^{\mathbb N}\mathbb R$ is not first-countable.  Suppose $\{U_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ were a countable neighborhood base at 0. Shrinking these sets if necessary, we can assume that $U_n\supseteq U_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and that each $U_n$ is a product of intervals of the form $U_n=\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}(-a(n,i),a(n,i))$ for some positive real numbers $a(n,i)$. Let $b(i)$ be positive real numbers such that $b(i)<a(n,i)$ for all $n\leq i$.  Then $V=\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}(-b(i),b(i))$ is a neighborhood of 0 and therefore includes some $U_n$.  Fix such an $n$, choose some $j>n$, and let $x=(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ where $x_j$ is chosen so that $b(j)<x_j<a(n,j)$ and where $x_i=0$ for all $i\neq j$.  Since $x$ has only one non-zero component, it is in $\Sigma^{\mathbb N}\mathbb R$.  It is in $U_n$ because $0\leq x_i<a(n,i)$ for all $i$, but it is not in $V$ because $x_j>b(j)$. This contradicts the choice of $U_n$.